# Can someone please explain to me how to solve $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac {\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{2x - 6}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please explain to me how to solve $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac {\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{2x - 6}$

In the following solution the only thing that I don't understand is the appearance of that minus sign before the limit after we include the divisor under root sign.

[solution on wolframalpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZuDD.png)

Comment: $\frac {\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{2x - 6} = \frac {\sqrt{1 - (9/x^2)}}{2 - (6/x)}$

Comment: $\frac {\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{2x - 6}=\frac {\sqrt{(x - 3)(x+3)}}{2(x - 3)}$

Comment: @CyclotomicField you're wrong if $x < 0$

Comment: @enzotib make the substitution $x \rightarrow -x$ then $x > 0$. Note the sign change when that happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push a positive number inside a square root, it squares itself:

$$3\sqrt{x+2} = \sqrt{9(x+2)} = \sqrt{9x+18}.$$

But when you try to push a negative number inside a square root, you have to leave its minus sign behind:

$$-3\sqrt{x+2} = -\sqrt{9(x+2)} = -\sqrt{9x+18},$$

because $\sqrt{9} = 3$ not $-3.$

When your number is a variable, it's not as obvious that there is a minus sign.  If $x$ is negative, then $-x$ is positive.  So in your problem the calculation is

$$\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2-9} = -\frac{1}{-x}\sqrt{x^2-9} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-x)^2}}\sqrt{x^2-9} $$

$$= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}\sqrt{x^2-9}=-\sqrt{\frac{x^2-9}{x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can change the variable
$$y = -x.$$
When $x \rightarrow -\infty$, then $y \rightarrow \infty$.
So that the problem becomes
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{y^2-9}}{-2y-6}= -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign derives from the absolute value:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{2x-6}\sim\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}}{2x}=\dfrac{|x|}{2x}=-\dfrac{x}{2x}\to-\dfrac{1}{2} \quad \text{as}\quad x\to-\infty
\end{equation}